# WPF Datagrid ignores SelectedItem changes if the item is not in the grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selecteditem

I have an ObservableCollection of "things" in my view model, and a couple filtered subsets of that list in additonal ObservableCollections.  I have two DataGrids on the screen, and I have bound them each to one of the subset ObservableCollections.

Both DataGrids have their SelectedItem property bound to a SelectedThing property in the view model.

When I change SelectedThing either programatically or by selecting a row in one of the two grids, it will change as expected.  If the item now pointed to by SelectedThing exists in a grid, the grid will update it's selected item.

So here is my problem... if SelectedThing does not exist in the grid's ItemSource, the selection acts like nothing happened and remains in whatever state it was in before SelectedThing was changed.  Ideally I would like the selected to Clear if the underlying view model property no longer is set to something in the grid's ItemsSource...  anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  Got it working.  In case it helps someone else in the future, here's what made it work...
In your code behind, register an event handler for the view model's PropertyChanged event, and then use that to check each grid to see if it contains the item being selected.  If not, then clear the selected in that grid.  I also modified my SelectedThing property to ignore incoming NULL values to avoid a deadlock (and in my app it will never be NULL after initialization)

_vm is a Property that returns my view model.

```
  _vm.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(_vm_PropertyChanged);

   void _vm_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedThing")
      {
          CheckSelection(grid1, _vm.SelectedThing);
          CheckSelection(grid2, _vm.SelectedThing);
      }
   }

   void CheckSelection(DataGrid grid, object selectedItem)
   {
      if (grid.ItemsSource != null)
      {
          bool itemInGrid = false;
          foreach (var item in grid.ItemsSource)
          {
              if (item == selectedItem)
              {
                  itemInGrid = true;
                  break;
              }
          }

          if (!itemInGrid) // clear selection
          {
              grid.SelectedItem = null;

              // not sure why, but this causes the highlight to clear.  Doesn't work otherwise
              grid.IsEnabled = false;
              grid.IsEnabled = true;
          }
      }
   }
```